# Reference USB without drive letter

Tags: windows, usb, installation, updates, drive-letter

My clients have a program which is housed on a flash drive. I'd like to send out an update (MSI or EXE) that erases one file on the drive and replaces it with another.

On Mac, this is easy since all external drives are referenced by name and stored in the same folder (e.g. Volumes/MyDrive), but Windows uses drive letters (F:\ E:\) that can change if the client has any different settings or even just another drive plugged in.

How can I reference the target flash drive without having to use a (possibly incorrect) drive letter?

Comment: Get the user to input the drive letter to perform the update.  Or supply a batch file that they can copy to the flash drive to kick off the upgrade, as  the batch file can report the drive it's being run from.

Comment: I'd prefer not to make the users do any work (if possible, that is) since most of them are not computer-savvy.

Comment: Try `wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=2 or DriveType=3" get DeviceID, DriveType, VolumeName, VolumeSerialNumber` if you are able to identify your flash drive in output (or in output from `wmic LogicalDisk get /value`) then you could parse it using `for /F` loop to get its drive letter.

Comment: Fantastic solution! Thank you so much @JosefZ!

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to give your own answer and then consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See JosefZ's comment for a great one-line solution to obtaining drive names in Windows.

I ended up using Java in the end. Here's the relevant code for future reference:

```
FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
File[] f = File.listRoots();
for(File file : f)
    System.out.println(fsv.getSystemDisplayName(file));
```